# Batch script with parameters with spaces

Tags: powershell, batch-file, sendmail

I am trying to find out how to execute a batch script passing 3 parameters that contain some spaces. 
This is how the script is being executed from the CMD:

```
sendmail.bat 'testmail@test.com' 'HCS Receiving Variance Notification' 'PO 2 \nLn 2\nLt G2036930  \nItm 10135910\nRcv 9.000\nOrd 3.000\n'
```

The script set the variables like this:

```
SET SUBJECT=%~2
SET MAIL_BODY=%~3
SET MAIL_LIST=%~1
```

But when I run the script in that way, the send-mailmessage PowerShell command (`powershell.exe send-mailmessage -subject '%SUBJECT%' -body '%MAIL_BODY%' -from test@test.com -to %MAIL_LIST%`) fails because the variable are wrong defined. The only one variable that is being set properly is the MAIL_LIST, then SUBJECT is being saved as "'HCS" and MAIL_BODY as "Receiving".

The is any option to have this working?

Thanks!

Comment: Why use a batch file at all? You don't need it. Just run `Send-MailMessage` directly in PowerShell.

Comment: Because JDE runs the script, and then the script save a log in Windows. Thanks for all your answers, using double quotes was the solution for this.